# Etiquette to reply to a 'Sorry, missed to tag you' email

Tags: united-states, email-etiquette

One of our product owners had sent an elaborate email about TODO tasks to the entire team. Within a few minutes s/he realized that I was not included in that email and forwarded it to me with the following email content.

> +WonderWoman
>
> Sorry, I missed you.

What is the professional/casual reply email etiquette to this?

P.S: The product owner has a cool persona.

Comment: Just reply to her only with a *"Received. I will begin working on my tasks from the list. Thanks."*

Comment: Just reply with: _'I missed you too darling, lots of hugs and kisses!'_ ;)

Comment: "I'll forgive you this time but don't let it happen again. ;-)"

Comment: Just reply "Got it, thanks".  It is a non-issue.

Comment: Did she "forward" it to you privately, or reply-all to the team with "+WonderWoman" etc?

Comment: @seventyeightist It was a reply-all with "+WonderWoman"

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Yes. One of such TODO tasks was addressed to me as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer should be the same as if you had gotten the original mail. (Especially if the PO does not expect an answer for the list, in which case you simply would not send a response at all)

Comment: Agreed, I wouldn't reply to this at all (unless there was something in the email asking for a response e.g. "please confirm you are ok to complete these tasks" or whatever). Assuming it was just a one-off mistake and isn't part of a systematic pattern of leaving you (OP) off relevant emails, that is (sounds like that isn't the case here).

Answer (score 7):

> What is the professional/casual reply email etiquette to this?

The response I would use would be:

### No problem, and thank you for making sure I got the information.

This should put the person at ease, and also let's them know you appreciate them making sure everyone who needed the information was included.